# Ansible: how to run task on other host inside one playbook?

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, ansible

I'm writing ansible playbook for one specific goal: i'd like to sync directory on server A-n, but before i should make git pull on server "B".
I launch playbook on host A-n (described in inventory).
I also have playbook for "git pull" on server B. 
Is it possible to include one playbook in another? I don't know how, because ansible allow to specify only one host group in beginning of playbook.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to run a task that's associated with a host, but  on different host, you should try [`delegate_to`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

Comment: But it's not possible to delegate whole playbook, not one task. Or maybe can i use another 'become_user' for such delegated task?

Comment: @Frexin : You can delegate a whole playbook with using delegate to the localhost ( ansible master) and calling `ansible-playbook` command.